# How to prove tail sum formula of XY, given that X and Y are jointly distributed and non-negative?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have come up with 2 approaches but I'm not sure which one would be more appropriate.

1) $E[XY] = \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} kP(X = k) * \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} tP(Y=t)$

2) $E[XY] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xyf_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$

I am asked to prove the following.

$$E[XY] = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X \geq m, Y \geq n)$$

Comment: Obviously, if you are asked to prove this, then X and Y must be discrete, and even, nonnegative and integer valued, hence (2) is irrelevant while (1) (once suitably rewritten, the current version being absurd) is one way to go (not the best, but...).

Comment: What approach would you suggest to go about proving the statement? Also, why would you say that (1) has to be rewritten?

Comment: (1) is unsound because the indices in the sums do not fit ($m$ and $n$ vs. $k$ and $t$).